# Regular Expression to capture entire list as one item- javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on js filter for string text and I want to use regex to capture entire list of list items, so I can count them and iterate throught them.

Please see what I am trying to achieve: https://regex101.com/r/Jd3JYW/2/

I know how to capture lines separately using this regex `(^\*[^\*](.*)$)/gm` but I need to capture entire list so I can differentiate between two lists, so I can make each of them start from n.1.

I expected the following code to work  `((^\*[^\*](.*)$)+)/gm` I thought that this wil capture first item (as it works for separate lines) and also any following untill patern is broken. However it is not working, I am still getting separate lines captured. Do you have any idea guys, how to capture whole list? Thank you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works. Thank you!

Comment: Adam, I posted a variation of the regex that also supports the last line as a part of the list.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. I really appreciate your help as well as explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `$` to match line endings, but it is a zero width assertion. You should use some *consuming* pattern to match line endings, like `[\r\n]+`:

```
/^(?:\*[^*\n].*(?:[\r\n]+|$))+/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jd3JYW/4%5C5)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?:^\*[^*\n].*(?:[\r\n]+|$))+` - 1 or more sequences of:

  - `\*`  - a `*` char
  - `[^*\n]` - a char other than LF and `*`
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `(?:[\r\n]+|$)` - either 1+ LF or CR symbols or end of a line (to match the last line).